# Rotating Camera moves the skeleton out of the armature (2.49b)

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

I decided to reinstall my Windows 7 because the install was showing it's age (2015). I reinstalled Blender 2.49b (for Fallout New Vegas meshes) and now have the problem that whenever I turn my camera by clicking the middle mouse button, the skeleton moves "out of the armature" like this:

[image: https://puu.sh/xiuTR.png]

[image: https://puu.sh/xivwd.png]

It "snaps back" after I release the middle button and e.g. scroll around to zoom in and out. It is highly irritating and I have no idea whether it will also affect exports. I tried reinstalling video drivers but everything is up to date as far as I know. I even reinstalled Windows 7 again to no avail.
Did anyone else encounter this issue and possibly knows a fix?

EDIT: Sorry, I'm apparently too dumb to have the images show here and it also removes my greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, consider this answered. I had "Driver Booster 4" check all my drivers and apparently the ones I downloaded directly from HP were too old. For anyone else having this issue I recommend either using that program or searching for updated drivers manually.